# Async/await redux thunk not returning promise to action correctly

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, sequelize.js

I have a thunk using Axios that's posting to an Express route using Sequelize.

The route is posting correctly (ie. data is getting added to the db) but the action inside of the React component isn't behaving as expected. Using `async/await`, I expect the action to wait until it completes the db post before continuing but that's not the case here. I'm getting `undefined` from the action.

The thunk hits the express route where I'm dispatching the action to update my redux store and returning the response:

```
const addedNewList = (newList) => ({type: ADD_NEW_LIST, newList})

export const addNewList = (name, userId) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post('/api/list/add', { name, userId })
    dispatch(addedNewList(data))
    return data
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

Using debugger, I can confirm that `return data` is in fact returning the response from the server that I need. I can also confirm that the redux store is getting updated correctly.

But here, when I try and access that response data as `result`, I get `undefined`:

```
  handleSubmit = async () => {
    const result = await this.props.addNewList(this.state.name, this.props.userId)

    // ** result is 'undefined' **

    this.handleClose()

    // pass off the results
  }
```

If I add a `setTimeout` after I evoke the `addNewList` action, it works as expected. This suggests to me that maybe it's not returning a promise? But my understanding was that if you returned the response from the server in the thunk, it would do that.

For completeness, here is my route which I've also confirmed with debugger that data is being passed as expected:

```
const userAuth = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next()
  }
  res.status(401).send('Unauthorized user')
}

router.post('/add', userAuth, async (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, userId } = req.body
  try {
    const list = await List.create({ name, userId })
    res.json(list)
  } catch(err) { next(err) }
})
```

Why is the action returning `undefined` in the `handleSubmit` method?

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the `dispatch` of `addedNewList(data)` instead:

```
export const addNewList = (name, userId) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post('/api/list/add', { name, userId })
    return Promise.resolve(dispatch(addedNewList(data)));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

That being said, you could consider restructuring the component to instead utilize `mapStateToProps` to use values/`result` from the updated Redux store rather than explicitly awaiting the response and manually passing the value?

Comment: shouldn't you use let and not const for await, thought I read something about const not being ideal with this.

Comment: I haven't heard about that, but you if you want to provide an alternative answer explaining why, it could only help get this issue resolved.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thanks for your help. I think suggesting to restructure the component is the right direction. What I'm actually doing after the action is called is to get the ID for the newly created list and use it to display an updated url via `history.push`. But I could easily do this by moving that into the components render and use the redux store for that information when it's ready.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky So it actually does work if I move the next step into render and just use `mapStateToProps` for the updated state. Your answer is correct in that I really just needed to restructure the component. Wrapping the dispatch with Promise became unnecessary after I did that though. Thanks!

Comment: @jami0821 Glad to hear you were able to resolve it! You may want to create an answer highlighting what you did specifically as it could help others experiencing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The response from Alexander got me on the right track so I'm sharing my solution in case it helps someone (as he suggested).

While I could have continued to try and solve this by wrapping the dispatch in a `Promise`, the better solution was to rethink how the component was structured.

In my situation, I wanted to get the ID for the newly created row in the database so that I could pass it into `history.push`.

```
  handleSubmit = async () => {
    const result = await this.props.addNewList(this.state.name, this.props.userId)

    this.handleClose()

    history.push(`/list/${result.id}`)
}
```

With `result` coming back `undefined`, the url was not updating correctly.

The better solution was to access the new data from the redux store where it was updated. This way I could be certain the history wouldn't get updated until the data was ready.

So my updated component now looked something like this where the history wouldn't update until a `newId` was available:

```
  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.props.addNewList(this.state.name, this.props.userId)
    this.handleClose()
  }

  render(){
    const { newId } = this.props

    if (newId) { 
      history.push(`/list/${newId}`)
    }

   return (
      ....
   )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    newId: state.list.newId
  }
}
```

Instead of putting this into render, I could probably also use a component lifecylcle method like `componentWillReceiveProps` or similar.